# click buttons on firefox with vbsscript on firefox

Tags: firefox, web, click, html

I'm new on vbs programming and I want some help. I want to make a vbs script proggram that will click button on a webpage . All I have found is about internet explorer. I want to click buttons on firefox
thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you see your question getting downvoted it is because it is a bit broad and lacks a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Is `vbs` a prerequisite? You might find easier solutions by simply using javascript / bookmarks, like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192559/205692)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AutoIt? Give it a chance --> [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: thanks for your reply also if I want to run it on another pc it requires any program to pre install?

Comment: it generates an standalone executable, no other dependencies are needed.